# Program to list all web files in a website

Tags: web-crawler

Is there a program that can scan a website via url and list out all of the files (html, js, css, images) that I can copy into Word? I need to list out all of the changed files for a website I've been working on.  There's a lot of files especially images.   Otherwise I would do it manually.

Comment: Google "web crawler"...you should see both open-source and commercial software. There are also open source web crawler frameworks such as crawler4j, nutch, etc. that you can use to build your own utilities.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` than you can check for changes with `diff`

Comment: Please try to elaborate on this answer (including detailed instructions), with such a short answer it's my opinion that you should have posted it as a comment instead.